# Issue with code (Node.js, React, PostgreSQL)

Tags: node.js, express

I'd like to start by saying that I am a beginner and only watched MERN project tutorials on YouTube to get started.

I'm working on a project to create a very simple web app using React and Node.js. I created a database on PostgreSQL and tried establishing a connection by setting up some routes. When I try to test to see if it works it doesn't work.

Here is the code in the server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt'); // Import bcrypt for password hashing
const pool = require("../db"); // connection to PostgreSQL database
const router = express.Router();

// Register a user
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    await pool.query('INSERT INTO "User"(username, password) VALUES($1, $2)', [username, hashedPassword]);
    res.send('User registered!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Login a user
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const result = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM "User" WHERE username = $1', [username]);
    const user = result.rows[0];
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send('Invalid username or password.');
    }
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).send('Invalid username or password.');
    }
    res.send('Logged in successfully!');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// Update a User
router.put("/:email", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email } = req.params;
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const updateUser = await pool.query(
      'UPDATE "User" SET username = $1, password = $2 WHERE email = $3',
      [username, password, email]
    );
    res.json("User Updated!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

//Test EndPoint

router.get("/test-connection", async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM \"User\" LIMIT 5;");
      res.json(result.rows);
  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send("Database connection failed!");
  }
});


module.exports = router;
```

I changed the code a few times, created a Test EndPoint, tried running my application (node server.js) but I get no result. I have no idea where I went wrong

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_... what does it do instead?

Comment: Also note that you technically [don't have a question in your post](/help/how-to-ask), so read through those posting guidelines and then [edit] your post to explain what you set out to do, what code you wrote to do that, what you expected that code to go given specific steps that others can reproduce, what you say it do, and how that differs from expectation. And of course, what you already did in terms of debugging and (re)searching to solve the problem yourself before posting.